# Using Python Social Auth to register an user via access token

Tags: python, ios, django, facebook, python-social-auth

How can I use Python Social Auth to register & log in an user via access token?

Not quite sure where to begin with this. I have an iOS client, who after signing into facebook's API, can POST an access token to my API.

I've looked at http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token, but I'n not sure how to extend that.

Any help would be great!